# Change values of a Char[]

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have this char array

```
 char[] E = {'f','e','d','c','b','a'};
```

I would like to know how to set the 3 first values of the array to `'G'`. For example in Matlab I used to do this:

```
F=[1 2 3 4 5 6];
F(1:3) = 9;// F = 9 9 9 4 5 6
```

Well this is an Integer example, but the idea is to set the values without extracting them from the array.

Comment: See [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in the tutorials.  Java uses c-like array syntax.

Comment: In Java, for naming an Array, we shall use camel casing. Like `values = ['a','b'];`

Comment: This site is unsuitable for teaching programming basics, because an answer understandable to a beginner would amount to a tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
Arrays.fill(char[], startIndex, endIndex, charValue);
```

Note: 
`startIndex` is **inclusive**. `endIndex` is **exclusive**. So you should use,

```
Arrays.fill(E, 0, 3, 'G'); // ['G','G','G','c','b','a']
```

And this `fill()` is an in-place operation, i.e. it operates on the same array.

Comment: I have edited your answer to include the 'exclusiveness` :)

Answer (score 4):

There are four ways I can think of to change the first 3 values of the array:

```
// Manually, one at a time
E[0] = 'G';
E[1] = 'G';
E[2] = 'G';

// Manually, cascaded
E[0] = E[1] = E[2] = 'G';

// Using a loop
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    E[i] = 'G';

// Using Arrays.fill
Arrays.fill(E, 0, 3, 'G');
```

Note: The last one internally does it using a loop. It is simply a nice convenience method.

The second one is the most efficient, but it is hardcoded to exactly the first three. If that's what you need, it's the best way.

If the range to update is more dynamic, the last one is best.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array and set the values:

```
int slice = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < slice; i++){
    E[i] = 'A';
}
```

Note: you could use a `if` condition to check that `slice` value is less than the length of the array to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
E[i]='G';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  E[i] = 'G';
}
```

sets the first 3 elements of `char[] E` to 'G'